# NullpointerException while replacing fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, replace, nullpointerexception

I have two Fragments (MainFragment and AnotherFragment) and MainActivity as described below.

In "onCreate" of MainActivity, I am adding MainFragment. Upon clicking I am adding AnotherFragment which takes data in two editText fields and pass them to mainfragment which display in textView fields.

MainFragment.java

```
Button a;
TextView t1,t2;
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    a = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.button);
    t1 = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textView);
    t2 = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    //a.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void showData(String a, String b) {
    t1.setText(a);
    t2.setText(b);
}
```

#### AnotherFragment.java

```
Button b;
EditText e1,e2;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_another, container, false);
    return rootView;
}

Comm comm;
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    comm = (Comm) activity;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    b = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.buttonA);
    e1 = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.editText);
    e2 = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    b.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    comm.sendData(e1.getText().toString(), e2.getText().toString());
}

public interface Comm {
    public void sendData(String a, String b);
}
```

#### MainActivity.java

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new MainFragment())
                .commit();
    }
}

@Override
public void sendData(String a, String b) {
    MainFragment mainFragment = new MainFragment();
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,mainFragment).commit();
    mainFragment.showData(a,b);
}

public void newone(View view) {
    AnotherFragment anotherFragment = new AnotherFragment();
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,anotherFragment).commit();
}
```

The fragment replace is causing nullpointerexception.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.exa.researchanddev.app.MainFragment.showData(MainFragment.java:31)
        at com.exa.researchanddev.app.MainActivity.sendData(MainActivity.java:57)
        at com.exa.researchanddev.app.AnotherFragment.onClick(AnotherFragment.java:42)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

And also,...

```
@Override
public void sendData(String a, String b) {
    Toast.makeText(this, a + " = "+ b, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    MainFragment mainFragment = new MainFragment();
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,mainFragment).commit();
    //mainFragment.showData(a,b);
}
```

when I commented the showData function the code is working fine. the fragments are getting replaced.

When not commented, NullPointerException is thrown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
@Override
public void sendData(String a, String b) {
    MainFragment mainFragment = new MainFragment();
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,mainFragment).commit();
    mainFragment.showData(a,b); 
}
```

The transaction of a Fragment is asynchronous. Because of this the TextViews in your Fragment are null. A better way would be to pass the Strings as arguments to the Fragment.

```
@Override
public void sendData(String a, String b) {
    MainFragment mainFragment = new MainFragment();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("A", a);
    bundle.putString("B", b);
    mainFragment.setArguments(bundle);
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,mainFragment).commit();

}
```

Now you can read the data of the arguments in your Fragments onCreateView.

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    a = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.button);
    t1 = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textView);
    t2 = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textView2);

    if (getArguments() != null) {
          t1.setText(getArguments().getString("A"));
          t2.setText(getArguments().getString("B"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here is that this:

```
a = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.button);
...
```

Is called before this

```
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_another, container, false);
```

The NPE that you are getting is because of the fact that you are trying to reference the ID of a view [`R.id.button`] from a layout that has yet to be inflated.

Try moving `a = ...` and the following variable assignments to after the view has been inflated.

Override the `onLayout` method, which will be called after the view has been inflated. In this, you should be able to do your variable assignments from layout.

```
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b){
    super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
    ...
}
```